# How to express that a variable belongs to a set in cplex call?

Tags: c++, cplex

I have a sensor node that has neighbors for example C (ij) to represent the set of neighbors of the point (ij). How is it presented with cplex and c++ in a constraint?

[image]

Comment: Please add *much more* detail. Including what you've tried so far (actual code). A [mcve] goes a long way.

Comment: i want to solve my linear program with cplex and c ++ my problem is how present the constraint above i can not say that at every change of the index (ah) the i will belong to a new set which is the neighbor of the node in the position (ah) in it is necessary to each change of the position (ah) the set C (ah) is changed and i will go through all this together.
Thank you I am a beginner with cplex is I have a project of end of study

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you have a look at all the examples provided in the CPLEX installation. The C++ ones are at `[yourInstallDir]/cplex/examples/src/cpp`. Start with `ilomipex1.cpp`.

A good place to start reading the documentation is at https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.9.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/UsrMan/topics/APIs/Cpp/cpp_synopsis.html